# Legend symbol size- ArcGIS 10.3.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, symbology, legend

I work with point layer in this size in the map:

[image]

[image]

When i create a Legend, the symbol size is to big:

[image]

I try to avoid from solve this issue by:

1. decrease the symbol size in the layer properties.
2. convert the Legend to graphics

How can i decrease the symbol size in the Legend and still remain with big symbol size in the map?

Answer (score 1):

Once you create your legend, right click on it and select "convert to graphics." Right click on it again and click "ungroup." This will allow you to resize legend items without changing the size on the map.

However, when data is updated in the table on contents, it will manually have to be updated in the legend from now on-- so I would recommend saving this part for the very end of your project.